# How to access to the ServiceManager with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I'm developing an Android app using Xamarin.Android. I have to access to the ServiceManager in order to retrieve a specific IBinder. The ServiceManager is accessible and visible by Java applications, but I cannot see it on my Visual Studio project with the referenced Mono.Android dll.

Relative Java code:

```
IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService("<service-name>");
```

How can I get the same behaviour on C# with Xamarin.Android library?

Comment: That's a class marked with `@hide` annotation so you cannot access in Java either. Try to use other public API please.

Answer (score 1):

try in your activity this: var a = Application.GetSystemService ("name-service");

Good luck